# Converting three lists into one list in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I'm new to haskell and am working on a function called `combineAll`.

Its input is going to be three integer lists, and its output will be one integer list.

It's going to return a sum of the three lists in corresponding order.

For example, if the input value is :

```
[[1,0,0,0],[1,1,1,0],[1,1,0,0]]
```

Then the output value will be :

```
[3,2,1,0]
```

I defined its signature as:

```
combineAll :: [[Int]] -> [Int]
```

I tried `zipWith (+)` but since it takes two inputs, it seems impossible for me to build up the recursion.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hint: take a close look at the types of `foldr` and `zipWith (+)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn this problem on its side with `transpose`, and transform the resulting list with `map`.

The mapping function will be ..... .

To find out what it is, see what will be the type of each element, and what is the value we're interested in producing for them.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [zipWith3](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zipWith3) if you just want to zip 3 lists together.

Alternatively, a more generalised solution would be to *fold* the list by zipping two int lists together at a time.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a homework assignment, and you haven't shown code, so I'm not going to present a full solution with code, but generally:

You can `map head` across your list of lists. If you do that to `[[1,0,0,0],[1,1,1,0],[1,1,0,0]]` you'll get `[1, 1, 1]`. You can sum these to get `3`.

If you `map tail` across `[[1,0,0,0],[1,1,1,0],[1,1,0,0]]` you get `[[0,0,0],[1,1,0],[1,0,0]]`. If you apply this recursively, you can get the sums of corresponding elements of the lists in your list of lists.

Comment: check out `unfoldr (Just . traverse (splitAt 1))` if you haven't already. I find it fascinating. :) (`map tail` is bound to diverge, or necessitate much bookkeeping, unfortunately).

Comment: In my undisclosed solution, calling `combineAll` on either an empty list, or where the first element in the list of lists is empty both result in an empty list. Essentially I rewrote `transpose` without realizing it because it's very early in the day.

Comment: yes, but does it work for jagged lists? :)

Comment: Assumng the first element is the shortest. Yes, I know about assumptions. ;) If I helped point the OP vaguely in the right direction I'm happy with it.

Comment: another option is mapping `(take 1)` and `(drop 1)` instead. :)

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use the `transpose` function. With your input that will produce:

```
ghci> transpose [[1,0,0,0],[1,1,1,0],[1,1,0,0]]
[[1,1,1],[0,1,1],[0,1,0],[0,0,0]]
```